# Round up or down to nearest multiple of .05 in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Example, I have 221.52, 195.97, and 138.88. Now I want it to automatically round up or round down to the nearest multiple of .05, producing 221.50, 195.95, and 138.90. Is there a formula for this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes:

```
=mround(a1,.05)
```

This will round the cell in A1 to the nearest `.05`.

Comment: Heh, simple questions, simple answers.